# Looking for suggestions to model a database of Electrical Components

Tags: database-design, normalization, subtypes

We have a database of *electrical components* and I am trying to make sure I have a good design. I am not a database designer (my comfort zone is designing with these hardware components), so I am interested in some pointers that have more application to me than name/address type examples. I have read some basic blurbs on First, Second and Third Normal Forms.

## Sample tables

The tables shown bellow are just examples, there are many more points of data and categories of data, but want it to be a good, efficient design. The columns of my first table where all data is required for every entry might be:

- `Internal_Part_Number` (Set as PRIMARY KEY [PK])
- `Status`
- `Genre`
- `Description`
- `Manufacturer`
- `Manufacturer_Part_Number`

If the `Genre` values is `'Capacitor'`, we need additional information where the first three, but there are several optional columns that should be provided like ESR if the data is available:

- `Internal_Part_Number`
- `Capacitance`
- `Voltage`
- `ESR` (optional, not all `Components` have these specified)

However, if the `Genre` value is `'Resistor'`, we need different additional information with similar constraints on data as above:

- `Internal_Part_Number`
- `Resistance`
- `Power_Rating`
- `Temperature_Coefficient` (optional, but this never applies to `Capacitors`)

## Questions

- Should I be splitting up my first table?
- Or, do all data columns that always exist for a given row be in a single table even though the data is not very well grouped?

For reference, our *internal status* of the *part* does not really care about the *manufacturer* and vice versa, But they are both necessary to describe `Internal_Part_Number`, so I think they both belong in the same table don't they?

Then there are more data that further define a given `Part`. Do I `JOIN` those tables to the first table on `Genre` when creating a view for that specific `Genre`?

How about when there are 50% of the attributes that are optional to populate to describe that `Part`, should each one be its own table that you would `JOIN` them all on `Internal_Part_Number`?

Obviously, we have a `Part_Number` that can be used as PK.

If I normalize this, I would have my master table as above, but would be creating a separate table called genres(cap and res, etc). Then another table called parametric list( where all parametric names live), another table to relate genres to parametrics, then finally a table that would have part Id, parametric Id, and value.

However, sometimes that value is a string, sometimes it's an enumeration, sometimes it's a number with units.

How would I link these tables to each other and how would I create a sql query that could create a table specific to the genre?